# Promixity in collection

Tags: f#

#### Original Question

I want to use F# to find the proximity of consonants to vowels in a collection of words.  So for example in the word "top" T is (-1: 1) from a vowel and P is (1: 1) from the vowel.

The first number in the pair is the position and the second number is the number of times it's in that position, relative to the nearest vowel.

In "consonants", C is (-1:1), N is (1: 3) , (-2: 1), (-1, 1), S is (2: 1), (-1:1),(3: 1) and T is (2: 1).

I suspect that I have to use a combination of groupBy, findIndex and countBy.

```
type ConsonantPos = { Name: string
                      BeforeVowel: int
                      AfterVowel: int }

let isVowel (x:string) =
    List.contains x ["a";"e"; "i"; "o"; "u"]

let consonantPosVsVowel x lst = 
      let rec getConsonanatPos x beforeVowel afterVowel currentPos lst = 
          match lst with
            | [] -> {Name = x; BeforeVowel = beforeVowel; AfterVowel = afterVowel}
            | h::t -> 
              if isVowel h then
                {Name = x; BeforeVowel = beforeVowel; AfterVowel = afterVowel}
              else 
                getConsonanatPos  x (beforeVowel - 1) (afterVowel + 1) (currentPos + 1) t

      getConsonanatPos x 0 0 0 lst


["b"; "a"; "c"] |> consonantPosVsVowel "b"
// val it : ConsonantPos = {Name = "b"; BeforeVowel = -1; AfterVowel = 1;}
["b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f"; "g"] |> consonantPosVsVowel "b"
// val it : ConsonantPos = {Name = "b"; BeforeVowel = -3; AfterVowel = 3;}
```

#### Revised Solution

As of 21/11/2018 both suggestions worked and worked well for the problem as I  orginally specified.

Of course this question was just a part of the program that I was writing.  As I have extended the program and explored the data, [BEEP](http://svr-www.eng.cam.ac.uk/comp.speech/Section1/Lexical/beep.html), one response proved easier to reuse: that is the one I have marked as the answer.

My problem, as it turned out, was my lack of understanding of and my inability to use collections.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: I am trying things as I go.  I hope that I'll work it out.

Comment: In your edit _Revised Solution_, you did change the rules somewhat, so that they do not really match the _Original Question_ any more. You are now also determining the distance of consonants to word boundaries. But this is fine, I'm happy that you found whatever was needed to float your boat.

Comment: When I started looking at the problem, I had **no idea** where to start.  As you stated, my actual needs turned out to be slightly different from what I wrote in the question.  That is why I left the original question unchanged.  Thanks to you, kaefer, and AMieres not only did I manage to solve my real problem but I also learnt a lot.  Before I posted the question I had tried, for several hours, to find a solution.  It's astonishing to me that two people worked out, and coded, a solution to my original problem in under an hour from posting it!  I am so grateful: I love the Stack community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach, which breaks down the task differently.

- Map the element to itself with its tail (negative distance, forward) and heads
  (positive, backward). This is done with a recursive function and two
  accumulators
- Filter the resulting list for elements not being vowels
- Map it to pairs of options representing negative and positive distances, with
  another recursive function, and collect these pairs into a flat list
  again while transposing their values
- Group this list by the elements, and map the result to a tuple of distance and number of occurance

```
let genTail2 xss =
    let rec aux accl accr = function
    | [] -> List.rev accr
    | x::xs -> aux (x::accl) ((x, (xs, accl))::accr) xs
    aux [] [] xss
// val genTail2 : xss:'a list -> ('a * ('a list * 'a list)) list

let dist2 pred (x, (ls, rs)) =
    let rec aux n i = function
    | [] -> None
    | y::ys -> if pred y then Some(x, n) else aux (n + i) i ys
    aux -1 -1 ls, aux 1 1 rs
// val dist2 :
//   pred:('a -> bool) ->
//     x:'b * ('a list * 'a list) -> ('b * int) option * ('b * int) option

let tuple2List = function
| None, None -> []
| Some x, None | None, Some x -> [x]
| Some x, Some y -> [y; x]
// val tuple2List : 'a option * 'a option -> 'a list

let isVowel = ResizeArray['a';'e';'i';'o';'u'].Contains
// val isVowel : (char -> bool)    

"consonants"
|> fun s -> s.ToLower()
|> Seq.toList
|> genTail2
|> List.filter (fst >> isVowel >> not)
|> List.collect (dist2 isVowel >> tuple2List)
|> Seq.groupBy fst
|> Seq.map (fun (x, xs) -> x, Seq.countBy snd xs)
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like it works too!  I am not surprised that I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: This response proved to be the flexible, easy to understand and easy to reuse.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let isVowel (x:char) =
    List.contains x ['a';'e'; 'i'; 'o'; 'u']

let countConsonants (word:string) =
    let vowelsp, consonants =
        word
        |> Seq.mapi(fun i c-> c,i )
        |> Seq.toArray
        |> Array.partition (fst >> isVowel)
    let vowels = vowelsp |> Array.map snd
    consonants
    |> Seq.collect (fun (c,i) -> 
        match vowels |> Array.tryFindIndex ((<) i) with
        | None   -> [ vowels.Length - 1 ]
        | Some j -> [ j - 1     ; j     ]
        |> Seq.choose (fun j -> 
            if j < 0 then None else
            Some(c, i - vowels.[j])
        )
    )
    |> Seq.countBy id
    |> Seq.map (fun ((l,p), c) -> (l,(p, c)) )
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.map (fun (l, s) -> l, s |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toArray)
    |> Seq.toArray

"consonants"
|> countConsonants
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Comment: Oh, that looks like it might work!  I need to check it out and watch a film with the wife... could be a while